# How to use struts tags to output byte[] as String

Tags: struts2

i am using hibernate to save large amount of text as BLOB in the DB. Thus I have a class instance as byte[].

```
public class News {
  ...
  private byte[] content;

  // getter and setter
  ...
}
```

I am trying to output such variable as String in JSP, e.g. using `<s:property>` tag. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: And why don't you make the conversion from bytes to string in this News class? This would avoid forcing all the callers to do it, without even knowing what this content is, which encoding to use, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet Did you mea keeping the class variable still as byte[], but returning a String in its getter? Wouldn't that cause any mapping problem with hibernate?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You could also keep the getter returning a byte array, if needed, and add one which returns it as a string. I wouldn't cause any problem with Hibernate if the annotations are on the fields. If the annotations are on the getters, just make sure to add an @Transient annotation on the getter returning a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 uses OGNL http://commons.apache.org/ognl/. So in JSP do it like you would do it in Java.

```
<s:property value="new java.lang.String(news.content)"/>
```